# Importing StanfordNER Tagger Google Colab

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, google-colaboratory

I am having some issues when trying to import StanfordNER Tagger to use for NER. Here is my code (took portions of this from other posts here):

```
import os
def install_java():
  !apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
  os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
  !java -version
install_java()

!pip install StanfordCoreNLP
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('stanford-corenlp', lang='en', memory='4g')
```

The error I am getting highlights the last line of code telling me:

```
OSError: stanford-corenlp is not a directory.
```

Any help would be great!

Edit: Here is another line of code that worked for me. For what inside StanfordNERTagger, load those files into Colab and give the path name. Do the same for what I originally asked as my problem above. Worked for me.

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize



st = StanfordNERTagger('/content/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
                   '/content/stanford-ner.jar',
                   encoding='utf-8')

text = 'While in France, Christine Lagarde discussed short-term stimulus efforts in a recent interview with the Wall Street Journal.'

tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)

print(classified_text)
```

Comment: What is the `!` syntax? isn't valid for me on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @C.Nivs The "!" is a method to run pip in Google Colab. Pip installing any package requires that (to my knowledge).

Comment: Did u find the answer to this question? I want to use Stanford model in Google Colab and I have the same problem!

Comment: @Paniz Just added in the edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code downloads all the required files and also sets the environment:

```py
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk

!wget 'https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2018-10-16.zip'
!unzip stanford-ner-2018-10-16.zip

nltk.download('punkt')

st = StanfordNERTagger('/content/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
                       '/content/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner.jar',
                       encoding='utf-8')

text = 'While in France, Christine Lagarde discussed short-term stimulus efforts in a recent interview with the Wall Street Journal.'

tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)
```